# "Whenever I discuss X, people don't know what I'm talking about" -- why the progressive tense?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-tense, descriptive-grammar, present-progressive

Consider the two sentences:

> Whenever I discuss X, [people don't know what I'm talking about](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22people+don%27t+know+what+I%27m+talking+about%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=zftlVpKoFcmrUbLqr5AG).
>
> Whenever I discuss X, [people don't know what I talk about](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22people%20don%27t%20know%20what%20I%20talk%20about%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=gfVlVonLHoraUf_amoAE#q=%22people%20don%27t%20know%20what%20I%20talk%20about%22).

I think the first one should be obviously idiomatic to any anglophone, while the second one sounds unnatural, ungrammatical, and wrong. But why?

"Whenever" implies regularity, a repeated action, so we use the Present Simple tense. Hence, it should be **"discuss"**, **"know"**, and **"talk"**. Instead, **"talking"** is idiomatic.

**Can anyone provide a good grammatical rationale for this phenomenon?** I would appreciate any authoritative references since I'm drawing a blank.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, I can't point to references, but if you're discussing something what you're talking about is what's being said then and there, whereas "what I talk about" doesn't link it in time to the discussing.

Comment: The verb "discuss" is not the only verb that allows this construction.  "Whenever I leave the building, people don't know where I'm going."

Comment: @michael_timofeev Good point, Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a bit idiomatic.

Skip the *whenever*. You say, *I just went to the show.* Your listener responds *I don't know what you **are talking about.***

We regularly use *talking about* to refer to the subject of a discourse, even a completed one. We could say *I don't know what you just talked about*, but that is not the norm.

No references. No rule. Just impression.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to my ear that the first one is correct. The "whenever" seems to give the sense of "during" - "During the times when I am discussing X..." so during each short period of time that I am discussing X, I am talking about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I disagree that "whenever" implies duration. It means "every time something happens", or "every time".